# Socket.io is not defined in console when hosted

Tags: javascript, html, socket.io

I am a newbie to socket.io and hosting on a Raspberry Pi so I come here to ask help!
I currently want to run a live chat on my web-page which is being hosted on apache2 with the domain of `tuckermedia.org`. When I run it locally, I do not get the error when I run nodemon server.js and it runs at it should but this doesn't seem to work on the Raspberry Pi.

When I host it on my Raspberry Pi, I constantly get this error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: io is not defined` (Screen Shot below)

[https://i.stack.imgur.com/asfu2.jpg][1]

Now, I have changed my script SRC to: `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.3.0/socket.io.js"></script>` This is what it currently is.

This however still gives me the same issue. I ensured that I have socket.io, nodemon, and the other packages that I needed. I also ensured that I started the server with nodemon but I still get the same error.

Nodemon screenshot on Raspberry Pi: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ao98P.jpg

If you can help me out, thanks! You can also message me on discord at Logans#9830 if you would like to have a conversation. Thanks!

HTML Code: https://pastebin.com/aGhqFFm8

script.js (client side) code: https://pastebin.com/XkXJPDb2

server.js (server side) code: https://pastebin.com/YYvK1dwd

Here is the console sources on my Raspberry Pi compared to it being hosted locally.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/oHndj.jpg

It seems that some of my files don't even show up like they should.

Comment: is `io` defined globally in your code?

Comment: Welcome Logan! Please give us more information if you want our help. Your question is way to vague. Copy/pasted codes would also do better than screenshots.

Comment: @Salketer Sorry for the inconvenience, it was early in the morning. I have rewritten the question in more detail!

Comment: @ButchMonkey I have updated the question to provide more detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's should be a correct link to *socket.io* at your frontend code. I suppose your path to script is the following one:

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

Try this one:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.3.0/socket.io.js"></script>
```

Source: https://cdnjs.com/libraries/socket.io